# Broadcasting SMS from android on boot complete

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get SMS broadcasted to few mobile numbers every time the sim card is changed. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I try it on my device. Can someone identify the issue in my following code please. The onBoot permissions are all added.

```
public class SendSmsOnTheft extends BroadcastReceiver
{

static void sendSMS(String destinationAddress, String text, Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SendSmsOnTheft.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, text, pendingintent, null);
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.d("VogueTools", "Got the Boot Event>>>");
            TelephonyManager telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService("phone");
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("file", 0);
            String number1 = sharedpreferences.getString("no1", "");
            String number2 = sharedpreferences.getString("no2", "");
            String number3 = sharedpreferences.getString("no3", "");
            String number4 = sharedpreferences.getString("no4", "");
            String extra = ("Mobile of IMEI NO: ")+ 
                         telephonymanager.getDeviceId()+
                         " is currently used" +
                         " by the SIM card service provider:" +
                         telephonymanager.getSimOperatorName().toString();
            String simno = sharedpreferences.getString("simno", "");
            String serialno = ((TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService("phone")).getSimSerialNumber();
            if (number1.length() == 0)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (simno.equals(serialno))
            {
            sendSMS(number1, extra, context);
            sendSMS(number2, extra, context);
            sendSMS(number3, extra, context);
            sendSMS(number4, extra, context);
            }
        }

    System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: How does it not work?  At what point in the code does it fail?

Comment: Try Removing   System.exit(0); 2nd time.

Comment: Show the Logcat of you App.

Comment: You should tell us where your code is breaking.. otherwise, post the logs here!!

Comment: No LogCat at all.. The app just doesn't behave as it should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I used in my app for the same purpose:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListeningToBoot extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String urphone = tm.getLine1Number();
            Log.v("Uphone","is "+urphone);
            Toast.makeText(context, "MDN:"+urphone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MySimPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String mobile_No=prefs.getString("MDN", "un-known");
            Log.v("from shared pref","MDN"+mobile_No);
            String imei=prefs.getString("IMEI", "un-known");
            Log.v("from shared pref","IMEI"+imei);

            if(urphone.equals(mobile_No))
            {
                Log.v("MDN is same","shoudl do nothing");
                Toast.makeText(context, "MDN no change", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("MDN is not same","send a message to someone");
                SharedPreferences prefs_names = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String number_to_send=prefs_names.getString("Moblie_Number", "un-known");
                Toast.makeText(context, "MDN changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String message_to_send="Your mobile number chagned:\nNew Number: "+urphone+"\nIMEI: "+imei;
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number_to_send, null, message_to_send, null,null);
            }
        }           
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Make sure you have given all the required permissions in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a little more information in order to help you. Anyway, have you registered the receiver properly? You must have been something like this under application:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".SendSmsOnTheft"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

With permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have rechecked and the receiver is registered properly. Thanks for your help.